# R cran Impossible to install dependencies recursively from install_github from devtools

Tags: r, github, installation, devtools

I try to test my package developed on Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 7. For both platforms I work on R 3.3.1 (but I also test on 3.3.0).

My package is saved on my GitHub repo (https://github.com/charlottesirot/elementR). When I run this command from Ubuntu, no problem happens:

```
    library(devtools)
    install_github("charlottesirot/elementR", dependencies = T , force = T)
```

but with windows 7, I have the following answer:

> Downloading GitHub repo charlottesirot/elementR@master from URL
>   https://api.github.com/repos/charlottesirot/elementR/zipball/master
>   Installing elementR "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/i386/R" --no-site-file
>   --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \   INSTALL  \   "C:/Users/Cha/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUX1GVA/devtoolsa907a336b/charlottesirot-elementR-103e064"
>   \   --library="C:/Users/Cha/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"
>   --install-tests
>
> - installing *source* package 'elementR' ...
>     ** R
>     ** inst
>     ** preparing package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :    there is no
>     package called 'XML' ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'elementR'
> - removing 'C:/Users/Cha/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/elementR' Error: Command failed (1)

As I understand, R tries to install the dependencies of my package (e.g. Shiny...) but it does not manage to install the dependencies of the dependencies (e.g. XML from gnumeric package)

Thus I try to manually install XML thinking that perhaps there was a problem with XML and then:

> - installing *source* package 'elementR' ...
>     ** R
>     ** inst
>     ** preparing package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    there
>     is no package called 'gtools' ERROR: lazy loading failed for package
>     'elementR'
> - removing 'C:/Users/Cha/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/elementR'

I cannot install all the packages manually, it does not make sense !!!

Moreover when I try something less cryptic than my package, thinking that I could makea mistake in my code:

```
install_github("hadley/ggplot2", force = T)
```

- installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** tests
  ** preparing package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :    there is no package called 'assertthat' ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
- removing 'C:/Users/Cha/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/ggplot2'
- restoring previous 'C:/Users/Cha/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/ggplot2' Error: Command failed (1
  )

I think there is a problem from the install_github ???
What do you think ??

Here is my Namespace:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")

importFrom(R6, R6Class)
importFrom(shinyjs, colourInput)
importFrom(shinyjs, delay)
importFrom(shinyjs, useShinyjs)
importFrom(gnumeric, read.gnumeric.sheet)
importFrom(abind, abind)
importFrom(tcltk2, tk2text)
importFrom(gdata, read.xls)
importFrom("readODS", read.ods)
importFrom("grDevices", "bmp", "colorRampPalette", "dev.off", "jpeg",
             "png", "rainbow", "tiff")
importFrom("graphics", "abline", "layout", "legend", "mtext", "par",
             "plot", "points", "rect", "text", "title")
importFrom("stats", "sd")
importFrom("utils", "read.table", "write.csv", "write.table")

import(shinydashboard, shiny, stringr, lmtest, reader, devtools, tcltk)
```

For me, it looks ok but what do you think ?

I looked at a lot of article on internet but I only found one message which is exactly the same than my case but it is not enough informative :
[Cannot install "flexdashboard package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533880/cannot-install-flexdashboard-package)

I am totally stuck at this point and I would like to have your help regarding this issue.

Thank you verrrrrry much in advance !!

CHa

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I encountered a similar or maybe related issue. As it turned out, there was a bug in devtools `install_github`, missing the correct installation of dependencies, despite `dependecies=TRUE`. Have a look at: [Does install_github recursively install dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425529/does-install-github-recursively-install-dependencies/38439733#38439733) If the problem persists, better contact the authors directly via their github repository.

Plus, I just observed another issue arising after a Windows update, during which permissions seemed to have been altered to download or update packages into personal Win User libraries instead of the "default" R library folder. I suspect devtools seemed consequently lost as to which packages were loaded or available at which versioning. A fresh R reinstallation (i.e., library folder cleansing) solved that issue, but such may not always be convenient.

Comment: this is useful information, but I think this implies that the question should be closed as a duplicate of the linked question??

Comment: that depends on whether it provides a solution; it may at least be linked? I had some negative experiences on questions being marked as duplicated which finally were not duplicates but thus remained unanswered.

Comment: I agree. The OP of this question was "last seen on August 29" according to their profile, so we may never find out ...

Comment: Sorry I just saw your answers !!! My fault :D, anyway, apparently it was a bug from install github but see https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1298
And again thanks for your answers !!